# Fixing ValueError from a password storing program

Tags: python

I recently made a program that followed up on a tutorial I watched but I seem to have run into an issue. The program has to store, view and add passwords when inputted to the user. Although, every time I try to run I keep getting a ValueError within the view function. How do I fix this? The error is posted below the code.

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

'''
def write_key():
    key = Fernet.generate_key()
    with open("key.key", "wb") as key_file:
        key_file.write(key)
'''

def load_key():
    file = open("key.key", "rb")
    key = file.read()
    file.close()
    return key

key = load_key()
fer = Fernet(key)

def view():
    with open('passwords.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            data = line.rstrip()
            user, passw = data.split("|")
            print("User:", user, "| Password:",fer.decrypt(passw.encode()).decode())
def add():
    name = input('Account Name: ')
    pwd = input("Password: ")

    with open('passwords.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(name + "|" + fer.encrypt(pwd.encode()).decode() + "\n")

while True:
    mode = input("Would you like to add a new password or view existing ones (view, add), press q to quit? ").lower()
    if mode == "q":
        break
    if mode == "view":
        view()
    elif mode == "add":
        add()
    else:
        print("Invalid mode.")
        continue
```

This is the output and error I get:

```
 Would you like to add a new password or view existing ones (view, add), press q to quit? view
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-18-234bb8d48400> in <module>
         35         break
         36     if mode == "view":
    ---> 37         view()
         38     elif mode == "add":
         39         add()
    
    <ipython-input-18-234bb8d48400> in view()
         21         for line in f.readlines():
         22             data = line.rstrip()
    ---> 23             user, passw = data.split("|")
         24             print("User:", user, "| Password:",fer.decrypt(passw.encode()).decode())
         25 def add():

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: Please post the full error traceback, which should include an error message and a line number (probably several line numbers). `ValueError` can mean a *ton* of things.

Comment: What that error indicates is that there's a line of your file that has multiple vertical bars in it. So `data.split` is returning a list of more than two values, while you're only prepared to unpack into two.

Comment: yeah but how do i fix it.

Comment: Have you tried looking at what you've saved to the file? (Maybe the way you're encoding a password results in a `|` character?)

Comment: yes but that also doesn't work

Comment: That depends on what you *want* to happen. If one of the lines of your file is `A|B|C`, which part is the username and which is the password?

Comment: Post a [mre] and debugging details. Dump your "passwords.txt" file. I bet it contains a line with multiple "|" characters. Delete the file and test again.